# how do I find the length of input in C, when the input is via shell?

Tags: c, shell

Let's say, user types in

```
echo abc, de | ./test
```

in shell (already have test.c compiled), how do I get the length of input (in this case it's 7)?

Comment: is this what you mean by prototype? I'm kinda new to C `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: Since you're piping to stdin, the program needs to read all the input and count the characters, except for the newline at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of characters in standard input.

```
int main() {
    int n = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF) {
        n++;
    }
    n--; // Ignore final newline
    printf("%d chars\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hmm I can't do that because I will need the getchar() thing for later use, which will put the user input into an array, thus I need to get the length before using getchar(), so that I can set up the array :/

Comment: There's no way to know the length until you read it all. You should use `malloc()` to allocate an array of a default size. If the input exceeds this size, use `realloc()` to resize it, and repeat this until you read it all.

Comment: @chenchen "can't do that because I will need the getchar() thing for later use," is a new requirement.  Either 1) accept an answer here and post a new question with that requirement or 2) appending this new requirement to your  post.  Note that changing requirements tends to create a moving target - something not well received.